# Why is this element selecting itself?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to highlight a list item immediately preceded by the item being hovered.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>  <!-- this one should be highlighted when... -->
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>  <!-- ...this one is hovered -->
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, the selector I'm using, `li + li:hover`, for some reason is selecting itself.
`li:hover + li` selected the `li` immediately *following* the one hovered, but I need the one immediately *before* it.  Am I using the wrong selector?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnrpq/) demonstrating the problem:

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css but then again maybe someone can enlighten us all

Comment: The selector is doing exactly what it is supposed to be. There is currently no way in pure CSS to select the sibling _previous_ to an element. Javascript is needed for that.

Comment: You cannot traverse up the `DOM` in `CSS`.

Answer (score 4):

CSS combinators can only access descendants and later siblings. They cannot access previous ones.

Once CSS4 comes around, you can do this:

```
!li! + li:hover
```

(Note: syntax is not finalised, as far as I know)

However, in the mean time, try this:

```
ul, ul>li {transform:scaleY(-1)}
```

And reverse the order of items in the list.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQa6v/)

Comment: The demo was what I tried initially.  So if I'm understanding right, what I'm trying to accomplish isn't possible until CSS4 is adopted, correct?

Comment: Did your initial attempt include `transform`?

Comment: Interesting idea. Too bad the source order had to be reversed.

Comment: I don't think `!!` (`!` on both sides) was ever in any drafts, but oh well.

Comment: @Kolink - no, but the demo is still the opposite of what I need.  I can easily select the NEXT item in the list without any odd transforms.  It's starting to look like my only option is JS.

Comment: I don't know if you were paying attention, but in my demo it's the item ABOVE the one you're hovering that lights up.

Answer (score 1):

The plus selector selects the element *following* the plus. So `li + li:hover` is looking for a hovered `li` immediately *preceded* by another `li`

See [The Adjacent-Sibling Selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html)

This is a gap in CSS that it probably best filled with Javascript.